Android Launch Mode "SingleInstacne"
"singleInstance".
The behavior is the same as for "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task. Any activities started by this one open in a separate task.
This is from the official docs of android...
But, the two statements contrast in my opinion.
"The behavior is the same as for "singleTask" " AND "The activity is always the single and only member of its task"
With "singleTask" we only destroy activities above it, if present and not the activities below. But second statment is saying it will be the only activity in the task how??
I think there is a contradict in the two statements of google docs
